# Tamil typing help

Tags: gnome, keyboard, shortcut-keys, keyboard-layout, layout

I am typing a lot page by page using Tamil Unicode layout in Ubuntu 23.04. While typing in this layout I can only put full stop, only the comma character (,) cannot be typed. You can type a comma only by changing the keyboard layout. While typing a lot in Tamil it is difficult to have to change the keyboard layout every time. Please tell if there is an alternative.

Similarly to change layout Windows key + Shift or space key endru 2, or three keys, it will change to speed. If you use keys like scroll lock, F12, F10 to change the layout in single key, the layout will change only if you press that key and click OK. KDE desktop environment has many keys options to change the layout, but GNOME desktop environment has fewer key options to set the layout change option.

It will be very helpful for me if you provide a solution for these two problems.

Back note:
I am forced to type using Ubuntu GNOME desktop environment and Unicode Tamil keyboard layout only.

---

### Original question in Tamil:

நான் ubuntu 23.4 version இல் tamil unicode layout பயன்படுத்தி நிறைய பக்கம் பக்கமாக typing செய்கிறேன், இந்த layout இல் type செய்யும்போது full stop மட்டுமே வைக்க முடிகிறது, கமா/coma(,) மட்டும் type செய்ய முடியவில்லை, english
layout மாறினால்தான் கமா போட முடிகிறது, நிறைய தமிழில் type செய்யும்போது ஒவ்வொரு முறை layout change செய்ய கடினமாக உள்ளது.. இதற்கு மாற்று வழி இருந்தால் கூறவும் pls..

இதை போலவே layout change செய்ய win key+ shift or space key endru 2, அல்லது மூன்று key use செய்து மாறினால்தான் speed ஆக change ஆகுது, single key இல் layout change செய்ய scroll lock, F12, F10 போன்ற keys use செய்தால் அந்த key அழுத்தி ok கொடுத்தால் தான் layout change ஆகுது.. kde environment இல் layout change செய்ய நிறைய keys option உள்ளது ஆனால் Gnome Environment இல் layout change option set செய்ய குறைந்த keys options மட்டுமே உள்ளது.

இந்த 2 பிரச்சனைகளுக்கு தீர்வு(solution) தந்தால் எனக்கு மிகவும் helpfull ஆக இருக்கும்

பின் குறிப்பு:
நான் Ubuntu Gnome environment மற்றும் unicode tamil layout மட்டுமே பயன்படுத்தி type செய்ய வேண்டிய கட்டாயத்தில் உள்ளேன்....

Comment: Quick note - I can read tamil, and this is an entirely valid question. You might want to write the question in english as its the language used in almost all the Stack Exchange network sites

Comment: A beautiful script ... But I cant read it :-)

Comment: This is an English language site.

Answer (score 3):

There are multiple Tamil keyboard layouts available in Ubuntu 23.04, and you can further increase the options:

- Install the `ibus-m17n` package
- Log out and log in again

Now the list of available Tamil input source options in *Settings -> Keyboard -> Input Sources* should have expanded with a few m17n ones.

Comment: +1 ... for the answer and for managing to understand that beautiful script :-)

Comment: @Raffa: Google Translate can be helpful occasionally. ;) And now people have put that translation into the question too.

Comment: @Raffa: Google Translate எப்போதாவது உதவியாக இருக்கும். ;) இப்போது மக்கள் அந்த மொழிபெயர்ப்பையும் கேள்விக்குள்ளாக்கியுள்ளனர்   Do you really think this foreign language stuff is useful (for the **majority** of people) ?

Comment: @Luuk LOL … Probably and most likely certainly no, … I know for sure it’s not useful for me as I don’t understand it “yet” … But the script looks beautiful nonetheless.